# "Unable to find method ''void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.<init>(java.nio.channels.SeekableByteChannel)''"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

**The problem:** I'm currently using **Android Studio** and **Gradle** to compile code from a github repository ([00-Evan/shattered-pixel-dungeon](https://github.com/00-Evan/shattered-pixel-dungeon/)) and while I can run some tasks (tried 'desktop:release', 'desktop:debug'), gradle refuses to sync properly and every time I try to do it, an error log pops up:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
'void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.<init>(java.nio.channels.SeekableByteChannel)'

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.<init>(java.nio.channels.SeekableByteChannel)'
    at com.android.repository.util.InstallerUtil.unzip(InstallerUtil.java:99)
```

**Important:** I've had this issue before (while compiling previous version of this code) and back then downloading a specific version of SDK build tools (30.0.0 and 26.0.0 if I recall correctly) helped, however this doesn't help anymore.
Other people using this code don't report the same issue and I seem to be the only one.

Also for some reason android tasks also don't seem to work, as if the android studio didn't recognize them:

```
Task 'release' not found in project ':android'.

 * Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

**What I've tried:**

- Clearing cache and restarting Android Studio/my PC
- Enabling/disabling different build tools versions (see the "Important" section). At the moment I have tried enabling all 30.0.X and 26.0.X versions and disabling any newer versions that were enabled
- Browsed similar Stackoverflow threads, however they either didn't seem to apply to my situation or didn't include enough information. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52381075/apache-poi-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-commons-compress-archivers), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68982459/i-try-to-build-a-project-but-it-continuely-fails-the-build-with-two-errors) and [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343759/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-apache-commons-compress-utils-ioutils-readfully).
- Uninstalling Android Studio and re-downloading it from scratch.

**Additional info:**

- Android Studio version: Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 4 (Currently latest)
- Gradle version: 7.2 (I tried using 7.1.1, but that didn't solve the issue)

Answer (score 7):

For anyone looking for more information, this specific issue has been covered [in Google's issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/213757977).  In short, the problem stems from mismatched dependency resolution of Apache's `commons-compress` between `robovm-gradle-plugin` and Gradle itself. As for Shattered Pixel Dungeon, the fix is present [in this commit](https://github.com/00-Evan/shattered-pixel-dungeon/commit/1b28cd19b5f59a5a8b7b9acf4c3565b19033f378).

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was error with robovm, I was trying build libGDX for iOS on Windows PC, when I remove iOS project, error gone too.

Comment: what if i need the ios module?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, when you install android studio it will install the latest SDK and latest build tool version which is not compatible with the existing projects.

According to the [build.gradle](https://github.com/00-Evan/shattered-pixel-dungeon/blob/master/build.gradle) present in [00-Evan/shattered-pixel-dungeon](https://github.com/00-Evan/shattered-pixel-dungeon)

You should try installing the SDK version 30. And the SDK build tool version: 30.0.X.
It should work.

For me, it is working with SDK version 30 and build tool version 30.0.3.

And just make sure you have java version 8 as mentioned in build.gradle.

Answer (score 2):

Try to install `Android 11.0 (R)` or `Android 12.00 (S)` on the SDK Platform tab on the Android SDK. That fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 2):

After fresh Android Studio installation I've downloaded proposed `Android SDK` and `build tools`, but my project was configured for the older ones. Then issue happened. I fixed it by downloading appropriate `Android SDK` and `build tools`.

For example, if your project has `compileSdkVersion 31` value, then download `Android SDK 31` and `build tools 31.0.0`. In `Tools/SDK Manager/Show Package Details` you can find correct versions for your case.

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed in robovm version 2.3.20

https://github.com/MobiVM/robovm/commit/1f09667836e29418dfdece5474e7d11c2b779a2f

So to fix in libgdx I changed the dependency in the project build.gradle file from 2.3.8 to 2.3.20

e.g.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:2.3.8'
}
```

to

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:2.3.20'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able able to remove `buildToolsVersion` after migrating to `Hedgehog` (currently the preview build) and migrate AGP to the `com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.0-beta03` version. I also upgraded all my API to `34`. This might be too bleeding edge for many, but it does seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you build IOS version and face this problem during gradle sync, you might need to downgrade gradle build tools version. For me it was

```
buildToolsVersion "33.0.1"
compileSdkVersion 33
```

from

```
buildToolsVersion "34.0.0"
```